# extract the content of each cell in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell, type-conversion

I have an array called **(dataBig2)** that contains **20234 cells**.

Each cell contains N number of **rows** and **9** **columns** (the first 7 columns are **integer** and the last 2 are '**string**'). please see the attached image

[image: screen shot of dataBig2 array]

I'd like to obtain the actual content of each cell and store it in an array.

for example: the content of first cell is 30*9 **(see the attached image)**

[image]

I have tried this code so far! but unfortunately, I didn't get the content of each cell!!

by the way i cant use cell2mat because the content of the cell is not the same data type

```
for i=1:size(dataBig2,2)
    final{i}=dataBig2{i}(:,:);
end
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your desired output. what does the **content of the cell** means?

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, I'd like to get the content of each cell array! i have 20234 cells, each cell content N number of rows and 9 columns. i'd like to get the content of each cell array and store it into matrix! see the second image is an example of the content of one cell array.

Comment: You cannot convert this into a matrix because: 1) data type is not same. 2) Number of elements in each sub-cell is not same.

Comment: is there any way to store the data into variable or array?

Comment: Yes in a cell array (that you already have)

Comment: Dear Sadar but i want the content of each cell! please have a quick look to the first pic ..... the first pic shows that that i have 20234 cells but i only get the content if i use this line of code x=dataBig2{1}(:,:);

Comment: Here `dataBig2{1}(:,:)` is same as `dataBig2{1}` which is a cell array that you already have. You're just picking the cell at the first index of the  `dataBig2` cell array and that's exactly the reason why you get the same output in your loop as `final` in which you store all sub-cells of `dataBig2` one by one

Comment: don't use for.  start with vertcat; try: array2table(vertcat(dataBig2{:}))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate all of the `n x 9` arrays into one large `N x 9` array, you can use [vertcat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html):

```
final = vertcat(dataBig2{:});
```

`dataBig2{:}` puts the individual elements (the `n x 9` arrays) of the cell array into a comma-separated list, which `vertcat` concatenates vertically.